# Functions written in VB6 requires helpmigrate to Delphi

Tags: migration, pascal

i am struggling since 2 weeks to migrate my VB6 code to Delphi (with intermediate knowledge of Delphi).
As i stuck on this Function can someone please help me to convert following function (written in VB6) to Delphi: ( Thanks in advance)

```
Public Function ConvertIt(s As String) As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim i As Integer
  l = 0
  For i = 1 To Len(s)
  l = l + Asc(Mid$(s, i, 1)) * 256 ^ (4 - i)        
  Next
  ConvertIt = l
End Function
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. Which part do you have problem with? I trust you know most of it, such as `function ConvertIt(const S: string): Integer; var L: Integer; i: Integer; begin`...

Comment: Hi Andreas,  you saved my life.. :-) It works like charm. Many Thanks for your kind help !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know VB, but I assume that

- `Long` is a 32-bit signed integer,
- `Asc(c)` returns the ASCII value of the character `c`,
- `Mid$(s, i, 1)` returns the `i`th character of `s` (1-based indexing), and
- `^` is the binary exponentiation operator.

If so, noting that `256^(4 − i) = (2^8)^(4 − i) = 2^(32 − 8*i)`, the Pascal equivalent would be

```pascal
function ConvertIt(const S: string): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    Inc(Result, Ord(S[i]) shl (32 - 8*i))
end;
```